# How to use insert_or_assign in map for custom class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am using insert_or_assign of c++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign
this says that the mapped value is constructed using rvalue reference i.e. std::move.

Here is my custom class, which I am using as a key. Next is the value, which I am using as vector.
While I am trying to use uniform initialization, I get the compilation error. Also, if I use std::pair still I get an error.
I am unable to understand what that error really means? Here is the error and the code.

Without std::pair

```
g++ -std=c++17 map.cpp -o map.out
map.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
map.cpp:51:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<MyData, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::insert_or_assign(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   51 |    studentClasses.insert_or_assign( {36, "Naja"s}, {"class 5th"s});
```

With std::pair,  I get the following -

```
map.cpp:42:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   42 |    studentClasses.insert_or_assign( std::make_pair({36, "Naja"}, {"year 5"}));
      |     

                                                                   ^
```

Now, here is the entire code ,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyData
{
    private:
        int age;
      string name;
   public:
      int getAge()
      {
         return age;
      }
      string& getName()
      {
        return name; 
      }
      MyData(int age_val, string name_val): age(age_val), name(name_val) 
      {
         cout<<"Constructor invoked"<<endl;
      }
      bool operator <(const MyData &other) const
      {
         return age < other.age;
      }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::map<MyData, vector<string>> studentClasses;
   studentClasses.insert_or_assign( std::make_pair({36, "Naja"}, {"year 5"})); 
   //studentClasses.insert_or_assign( {36, "Naja"s}, {"class 5th"s}); 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`std::map<Key, T>::insert_or_assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) takes two parameters, one for the key and the other for the value:

You also need to invoke the constructor for `std::vector<std::string>` explicitly.

```cpp
// ...

studentClasses.insert_or_assign({ 36, "Naja"s }, std::vector { "year 5"s });
studentClasses.insert_or_assign({ 36, "Naja"s }, std::vector { "class 5th"s });

// ...
```

Comment: why to specify this explicitly std::vector?  We have studentCLasses which is a map of my class and vector, then why do we need to specify again vector?

Comment: @ankurkatiya Because if you look at the overload of[`std::map<K, V>::insert_or_assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign). The second parameter for `obj` actually uses a template parameter as its type which needs to be deduced by the compiler, which is why you need to do it explicitly for the second argument but not for the first.