# How to use emplace in map for custom class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdmap

Here is my custom class, which I am using as a key. Next is the value, which I am using as vector.
While I am trying to use uniform initialization, I get the compilation error.
I am unable to understand what that error really means? Here is the error and the code.

Based on the advise by somebody on insert - [How to use insert_or_assign in map for custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644729/how-to-use-insert-or-assign-in-map-for-custom-class#68644923)

I am using the similar thing for emplace(). However, it is not working.

The prototype of emplace says -

```
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

It means the Args && is nothing but rvalue reference of class Args right?

In my case, the arg is nothing but std::vector.
How can I do emplace?

```
class MyData
{
    private:
        int age;
      string name;
   public:
      int getAge() const
      {
         return age;
      }
      string& getName()
      {
        return name; 
      }
      MyData(int age_val, string name_val): age(age_val), name(name_val) 
      {
         cout<<"Constructor invoked"<<endl;
      }
      bool operator <(const MyData &other) const
      {
         return age < other.age;
      }
      MyData(const MyData& other)
      {
         cout<<"Copy constructor invoked"<<endl;
         age = other.age;
         name = other.name;
      }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::map<MyData, vector<string>> studentClasses;
   studentClasses.emplace({32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
   
    return 0;
}



In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
map.cpp:62:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<MyData, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::emplace(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)’
   62 |    studentClasses.emplace({32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
   
   574 |  emplace(_Args&&... __args)
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:574:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Comment: Life would be so much easier with a [mcve] that I could copy/paste with includes and all.

Answer (score 4):

I don't need it often but sometimes I need it: a "real" `emplace()` in a `std::map`. Most times it causes me some trouble until I get it working but most times I finally got.

My MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_literals;

struct MyData {
  int age;
  std::string name;
  
  MyData(int age, std::string name): age(age), name(name)
  {
    std::cout << "MyData::MyData(int, std::string)\n";
  }
  
  MyData(const MyData& myData): age(myData.age), name(myData.name)
  {
    std::cout << "MyData::MyData(const MyData&)\n";
  }
  
  MyData(MyData&& myData) noexcept:
    age(std::move(myData.age)), name(std::move(myData.name))
  {
    std::cout << "MyData::MyData(MyData&&)\n";
  }

  bool operator<(const MyData& myData) const
  {
    return age < myData.age
      || (age == myData.age && name < myData.name);
  }
};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << "Exec: " #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::map<MyData, std::vector<std::string>> studentClasses);
  DEBUG(studentClasses.emplace(MyData{32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s}));
  DEBUG(studentClasses.emplace<MyData>({32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s}));
  DEBUG(studentClasses.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(32, "SJ"s),
    std::forward_as_tuple(std::vector{ "working"s })));
}
```

Output:

```
Exec: std::map<MyData, std::vector<std::string>> studentClasses;
Exec: studentClasses.emplace(MyData{32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
MyData::MyData(MyData&&)
Exec: studentClasses.emplace<MyData>({32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
MyData::MyData(MyData&&)
Exec: studentClasses.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(32, "SJ"s), std::forward_as_tuple(std::vector{ "working"s }));
MyData::MyData(int, std::string)
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c9f887fdc73cd48)

1. I provided a move constructor. So, the first two emplace versions (copied from [songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68645571/7478597)) use that one. (Without a move constructor, `emplace()` would use the copy constructor of `MyData` instead – as pointed out by the OP.)
2. I used my last resort `piecewise_construct` (which already worked as well in C++11).
   This one does in fact the "real" `emplace` (i.e. in-place construction).

Further reading: [**cppreference.com: std::map::emplace()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

Answer (score 2):

> It means the Args && is nothing but rvalue reference of class Args right?
> In my case, the arg is nothing but std::vector. How can I do emplace?

Note that both key and value are passed to `emplace` to constructor the element in `map`. (BTW `Args&&` is not rvalue reference but [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references).)

The problem is that the braced-init-list like `{32, "SJ"s}` doesn't have type, which causes template argument deduction failing when calling `emplace`.

[Non-deduced contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

> 6. The parameter **P**, whose **A** is `a braced-init-list, but P is not std::initializer_list, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or (since C++17)` a reference to an array:

You can pass a `MyData` explicitly:

```
studentClasses.emplace(MyData{32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
```

Or specify template argument as:

```
studentClasses.emplace<MyData>({32, "SJ"s}, std::vector{"working"s});
```

Comment: This actually invokes the copy constructor and I guess, the entire point of using emplace is to do in-place construction and avoid copy constructor invokes.

Comment: @ankurkatiyar It seems the copy/move can't be avoided. If `MyData` has a converting constructor taking single argument, then `emplace` could avoid copy/move on `MyData`.